# Why is Sator not wearing a mask in this scene?

Tags: tenet

I do not understand the purpose of the breathing mask here:

[image: Image of Sator standing behind Kat in a chair. She is wearing a breathing mask, but Sator is not]

The scene is about retrieving the briefcase from Protagonist. Why is Sator not wearing a mask in this scene?

Comment: Related: (Movies & TV SE) [Can someone explain how Kat experienced this part of Tenet from her perspective?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110887/1006)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the air in the blue (inverted) room is also inverted. That is why Kat is wearing the mask, as she is non-inverted.